# What is the actual use of labels in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, label

I was reading docker-compose tutorials and want to understand more about `labels` 
I read that they can be used to store metadata. Is `labels` useful just to store metadata or Are there any other significant uses? Please help me to understand this more.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Labels are basically for metadata and don't have any specific effect as long as you aren't using them. So there are some use cases where labels come in handy:

- You want to filter the list of running containers based on some predefined criteria, so you could run `docker ps --filter "label=customer=customer1"`
- Labels can also be used for monitoring, so the monitoring system can read them and attach them to the metrics it gathers (e.g. when running cAdvisor)
- third-party tools can make use of labels to act on them automatically. For example see [the docs of the traefik proxy](https://docs.traefik.io/#2-launch-a-service-trfik-detects-it-and-creates-a-route-for-you) that uses docker labels to configure routing of dns names to containers (or more specifically to services)

So there is no direct implication of labels by docker but there are many use cases where this generic concept is a nice way to allow extending the technology.